# Inequality contrained optimization problem (contingency table)

Tags: optimization

I am concerned with the following optimization problem. I first state the problem and then briefly discus its background.

$$f(a_1,...,a_n)=\frac 1n \sum_1^n (a_i-b_i)^2$$

should be maximized subject to constraints:
$$\sum a_i=1$$
$$\sum b_i=1$$
$$ 0\le a_i \le 1$$
$$ 0\le b_i \le 1$$

The background is a square contingency table from which only the marginal proportions on one side ($b_i$) are known. The function gives the variance across the margins, where $a_i$ denotes the corresponding marginal proportions that are unknown. I am interested in the maximum variance conditional on the marginal distribution of one side of the table.

Thank you for advice on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I am not a pure mathematician, I have to look into some of the terms you are using.

Comment: (Alternatively you may explain to me what is the implication of your second comment :))